# Find script refrence in all scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

In unity I can find references of a particular script in open scene by right clicking on the script and selecting Find References in Scene as below:

[image]

But I am looking for a way to search a particular script reference in *all scenes* of the project. I searched but can't find anything. Is this possible to do? Maybe using and editor script?

Answer (score 2):

Unity load gameObjects including scripts only in active scenes. Thats the reason you can't "Find References" over all scenes...

Theres a little "workaround" to quick look all references if you using versioning tools like git.

1) Drag all your scenes in hierarchy(now they are all active).
[image: hierarchy]

2) Do your "Find References"
3) See your Result
4) Revert or remove unnecessary scenes after you got your references.